# Why does LyX keep resizing my graphics?

Tags: graphics, lyx

When I add graphics to my text (inside a float "figure") and then export to PDF, the picture is enlarged by something like 25% comparing to its original size.
While in the LyX file, the picture is shown as it is (original size).

What can I do to stop that from happening, instead of using "scale graphics" and setting it to 80% every time?

Comment: The size of graphics representation in the LyX GUI can be changed manually or switched off completely. See Tools -> Preferences. So it is independent from the LaTeX options you can set in the "insert graphics" popup. Maybe there is a LaTeX option for the preamble that resizes all graphics at once?

Comment: Please post a minimal example. Otherwise all we can do is fun. For more information, please read http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample